# Android Localization, When turning device to layout-land language goes back to default

Tags: android, localization

I have an app that I want to use in both english and hebrew.
I've added two String files under values and values-iw folders.
When a user is selecting a different language, I run this code:

```
Locale locale;
     if (location.equals("iw")){
         locale= new Locale("iw");
         Errors._langauge=1;    
     }
     else{
         locale=Locale.ENGLISH;
         Errors._langauge=2;
     }
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
          getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

This is working fine until I lay my device, causing the xml in layout-land directory to be loaded.
When the land xml is loaded the language goes back to default language of the system.
How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 2):

When changing the orientation, your Activity recreates itself, so your onCreate() gonna run again. I assume you are initializing the default value in your onCreate() method, so it changes itself back.

Comment: I don't change anything OnCreate. Further more, I change the launaguage , then goes to another xml (new Intenet) which calls its on Create, and get the right langauge. Just when I change that new Intenet to landscape The langauge goes back. I even tried to reset the language with the code above in the OnCreate method, still the same issue...

Comment: Then store the user's choice, and initialize the language with it on onCreate().

Comment: each time on create is called to load the language from saved prefrences?